# select distinct with difference

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have this table `columns_tab`:

```
INDEX_OWNER     INDEX_NAME           TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DUMMY           PK_FUL_REQUEST       CUSTOMERID, ID, INSTITUTIONID
NIR             PK_FUL_REQUEST       CUSTOMERID, ID, INSTITUTIONID
NIR             IX_REQUEST_HASH      CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID
DUMMY           UQ_REQUEST_HASH      CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID
```

I want to get the row where the text column is equal but the index_name is not equal.

I can do it with 2 same tables, but can I do it with one table?

Expected result is:

```
    INDEX_OWNER     INDEX_NAME           TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NIR             IX_REQUEST_HASH      CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID
DUMMY           UQ_REQUEST_HASH      CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID
```

The query for it can be achieved by

```
select index_owner, index_name, text
  from columns_tab a, columns_tab b
 where a.text = b.text
   and a.index_name != b.index_name
```

I want to achieve it without select twice from the same table.

Comment: Do you have any primary key on that table?

Comment: What's your expected result? Do you want to get all possible combinations, like 1 is not equal to 2,1 is not equal to 3, 2 is not equal to 3, and so on? Or do you want to just get the results ordered by text and then compare every neighbor index_name?

Comment: In your expected results example how do you know which row to pick? What is your criteria? I mean that there is two possible candidates in each pair.

Comment: I want the both of them. look at the query I wrote. I want the same thing but to query only once the table(if its possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select owner, index_name, text
  from (select t.*,
               count(*) over(partition by text, index_name) both_match,
               count(*) over(partition by text) text_match
          from COLUMNS_TAB t)
 where text_match > 1
   and both_match = 1;
```

But have to point out that if you are avoiding query table twice in terms of performance then my approach will not necessarily perform better. You should compare execution plans of both queries on your real data.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30a43/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE columns_tab ( INDEX_OWNER,     INDEX_NAME,           TEXT ) AS
          SELECT 'DUMMY', 'PK_FUL_REQUEST',  'CUSTOMERID, ID, INSTITUTIONID' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'NIR',   'PK_FUL_REQUEST',  'CUSTOMERID, ID, INSTITUTIONID' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'NIR',   'IX_REQUEST_HASH', 'CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'DUMMY', 'UQ_REQUEST_HASH', 'CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH prev_next AS (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAG( index_name  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY text ORDER BY index_name ) AS p_name,
         LEAD( index_name ) OVER ( PARTITION BY text ORDER BY index_name ) AS n_name
  FROM   columns_tab t
)
SELECT index_owner,
       index_name,
       text
FROM   prev_next
WHERE  index_name <> p_name
OR     index_name <> n_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30a43/5/0)**:

```
| INDEX_OWNER |      INDEX_NAME |                                TEXT |
|-------------|-----------------|-------------------------------------|
|         NIR | IX_REQUEST_HASH | CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID |
|       DUMMY | UQ_REQUEST_HASH | CUSTOMERID, HASH_KEY, INSTITUTIONID |
```